# Spring Security without spring core?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a really simple question, that I just can't find the answer.

If I want to use only Spring Security, do I need Spring core or any other dependency?

In [this link](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security), in the bottom I see only spring security jars as dependencies, but still I couldn't get it to work. I only got it to work when I used a lot more of spring jars (core, context, and more).

So, what are the minimal dependencies I need for using Spring Security? All I need is an authorization and authentication framework, and I want as little dependencies as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: You answered both of your questions.  No, you can't use Spring Security without Spring core.  You know you need core and context.  As for "more", keep adding until you don't get ClassNotFoundException.  That's the minimal set. Does Spring Security have a Maven project that pulls in your dependencies for you?

Comment: Check the [FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-what-dependencies) and the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#appendix-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

For every spring extension you need to use Srping core, because every extension is build on top of spring core